# Where should I put the "Definition of concepts" section in a Research Paper

Tags: writing, writing-style

I'm writing a research paper and there are some concepts which I think would help a reader to understand the study better. However, I'm not sure where to put this section. Should I put it right after the Introduction? Or before Literature Review?

Comment: I decided to put it below the introduction since in this way it helps reader to understand the experiment better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the section in question before the first section, where the concepts you want to define are mentioned. However, note that, generally, you have **two options**, in my opinion. The first is to collect definitions (potentially, with brief explanations) under a *separate section*, which is usually called "Definitions of Terms". The second option is not to have a separate section, but to present the concepts' definitions and explanations as your paper's story line unfolds. While the benefit of having a separate section is clarity and ease of use for less advanced readers, the advantage of *embedding concepts' definitions and explanations* into the paper's main text is an opportunity to provide much more detailed explanations as well as smooth integration with the rest of material.

Comment: @MajidHassanpour: You're welcome.

Comment: I agree with this answer, If you do choose to include a "glossary" or "Definitions of Terms", it should go at the beginning of your paper.

Answer (score 2):

Conventions like this vary between fields.  Look at other papers in your field or subfield, and do what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Definitions of key concepts are important to the understanding of your paper. Hence, it is preferable to have them as a separate section under the title "Definition of terms." This section should be be placed towards the beginning of the paper, before you start with the major content. I would place it in the introduction, immediately after the statement of the problem at hand and the purpose of the study.

Answer (score 0):

Right in the introduction / Background.  That's where you introduce everything, including concepts the reader needs to know.